# check uniqueness of excel column in java

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I'm using Apache POI API for extracting data from an uploaded excel (.xls or .xlsx) file in my web application. Now I want to validate that a particular column of the sheet should contain unique data (no repeated entries).

Is it possible to check uniqueness before actual extraction of data is started (purpose is reduction of computation only)? I can do it after extraction because I'm putting that column in a set.

Or is there any other way to do this kind of thing? Could you give me the solution or send me in the right direction?

Comment: What do you consider as unique? Same value? Same value with the same formatting? Same displayed value no matter how it's stored (eg 1 vs '1) ?

Comment: 1 or '1' is not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at [AutoFilter](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/AutoFilter.html).

From the documentation:

> For example, you can filter to see only the values that you specify,
>   filter to see the top or bottom values, or filter to quickly see
>   duplicate values.